# Assign a value to a cell in a table using the cell id

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, web

I need to assign a value to a specific cell in a table in a jsp and have created a table with id 'table1':

Now to assign a value to a cell in this table using these commands:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table1" border = "1">

<%
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = "UP";
%>

<tr>
<th></th>
<th>DEV1</th>
<th>DEV2</th>
<th>SIT1</th>
<th>SIT2</th>
<th>UAT</th>
<th>NFT</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>SFG Process</td>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
<td>row 1, cell 4</td>
<td>row 1, cell 5</td>
<td>row 1, cell 6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>SCC Process</td>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
<td>row 2, cell 4</td>
<td>row 2, cell 5</td>
<td>row 2, cell 6</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However Tomcat is giving thsi error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /emt/xyz.jsp
var cannot be resolved to a type
6: <table id="table1" border = "1">
7: 
8: <%
9: var table = document.getElementById("table1");
10: table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = "UP";
11: %>
12: 


An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /emt/xyz.jsp
document cannot be resolved
6: <table id="table1" border = "1">
7: 
8: <%
9: var table = document.getElementById("table1");
10: table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = "UP";
11: %>
12: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Comment: It seems you're tring to use JavaScipt in a scriplet. Do you realize that scriptlets are Java code snippets executed at server-side, and JavaScript is code that is sent to the browser and executed by the browser?

Comment: I have recently started coding and using JavaScript so the answer is no I didn't know that. Can you guide me on what I need to do?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I have attached the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = "UP";
%>
```

You are writing java script code inside jsp, thus compilation failed.

You just remove that code there and add between `<script>` tags

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
  var table = document.getElementById("table1");
  table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = "UP";
</SCRIPT>
```

[See this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html)  for complete reference and an example too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Javascript for changing innerHTML!

```
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = "XYZ";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however still getting the same error. Please see the code and the error attached

Comment: Didn't know you are not using the <script> tag :D So answer is correct ;) Cheers!